# "ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(33): Subprocess for 'conda run xxx' " in 1.65.00 VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, conda

Today I run my python(.py) file as usual,but the terminal shows a new problem which I cannot solve for a long time.
Explicitly,I used to click Run Python File,

[image]

but the terminal shows that like this:

[image]

I then tried another two ways to run my python,such as "run code"(code runner provides),debug(python plugin together with "run python file"),and it shows that:
[image]
[image].

It is obvious that except the "debug",other two both fail to run,showing "ModuleNot..."(while actually the module exists in the vir env).
All codes are easy:

```
print('Hello World')
import os

print(os.path.abspath(__file__))
import numpy as np
```

Comment: Please post code and shell outputs as text, not images.

Answer (score 4):

go to vscode Extensions market and search "python". right click on "Python"(published by microsoft) and click on "Install another version". select a version that previously worked for you - usually just the one back before the current one.

Comment: I tried to figure out for hours why this is suddenly happening to me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Faced with the same issue.Solved by adding the following line

```
python.terminal.activateEnvironment" : false
```

to the settings.json file of the visual code

Comment: Thanks,later I found it may be the problem of the python plugin,so I rolled back the python plugin to the previous version and fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of Python extension in VSCode you have to add the Path for the conda by yourself. Go to the Python extension settings and add the path for the conda.exe.

[Screenshot of the needed setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsUKJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I felt so lost; what a strange error.
Yes, just install an earlier version of the vscode python extension.
I cannot understand how such a bug has been introduced into the extension.